# Get List of values from object list

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a class `Person` which has the field `String name`. In another class I have a list of `Person`s. Is it possible to get a list of the person's names using the Java 8 streaming API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, using [`Stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

```
personList.stream().map(p -> p.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Or, instead of `p -> p.getName()`, you could use a method reference `Person::getName`. It might be a bit more readable.

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach9

```
yourCollection
.stream().map(p -> p.getName())//here you have stream of names
```

now all you have to do is [convert this stream to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830313/retrieving-a-list-from-a-java-util-stream-stream-in-java8)

```
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So try

```
List<String> names = yourCollection
                     .stream()
                     .map(p -> p.getName())
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```