# How to get the String representation of all elements in a Java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Using Eclipse and Java -version 1.8

I have this code:

```
    public Stream<Ship> remainingShips() {
        return this.b.getShips().stream().filter(s -> !s.isSunk());.
    }

    public Stream<Ship> sunkShips() {
        return this.b.getShips().stream().filter(s -> s.isSunk());.
    }
```

I want to print out all the items in the stream, by calling

```
System.out.println("Sunk ships => " + this.opponent.sunkShips());
```

but this will just print the stream object, how can I get access to all the items in stream and print each out?

Comment: Might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830313/retrieving-a-list-from-a-java-util-stream-stream-in-java-8

Comment: Can you come up with better title for this question? Something like, "How to print all elements in stream?". Thanks

Comment: yep can do, have done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can iterate over the elements of the Stream and print them :

```
System.out.println("Sunk ships => ");
this.opponent.sunkShips().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or you can generate a List from the Stream and print it :

```
System.out.println("Sunk ships => " + this.opponent.sunkShips().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: thanks! what if I want to print the stream only if the stream has more than 0 items? is there a good way to do that with streams/filters in Java?

Comment: @AlexMills In order to find if a Stream is empty, you have to use some terminal operation (such as `findAny()` or `findFirst()`, which will close the Stream. Therefore I suggest you produce a List (`List<Ship> ships = this.opponent.sunkShips().collect(Collectors.toList();`) and print it if it's not empty.

Comment: There is no point in collecting into a `List` when you already know that you are only interested in a `String` representation. You can use, e.g. `.map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))`…