# Java Sort String 2 List and Compare them

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, arraylist

I want to sort 2 List and compare them, but sorted method did not work.
I have 2 String List which includes integer.

These are my Lists

```
List<String> WORD_OF_ADDRESS = gatekeeperPage.getWords(ADDRESS);
List<String> WORD_OF_CONTACT_ADDRESS = gatekeeperPage.getWords(CONTACT_ADDRESS);
```

My **getwords** method returns :  `return Arrays.asList(words);`

When I try this ;

```
Stream<Object> sortedList = Arrays.stream(WORD_OF_ADDRESS.toArray()).sorted();
System.out.println("SORTED LİST "+ sortedList);
```

I get this : `SORTED LİST java.util.stream.SortedOps$OfRef@3e8c3cb`

What should I do to sort 2 list ?

Comment: Collect to list after you sorted it : .collect(Collectors.toList())

Comment: I tried almost everything but it didn't work. I will try again.

Comment: [How to print out all the elements of a List in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10168066) [How to get the String representation of all elements in a Java 8 stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565865)

Comment: @BenoitCuvelier I tried now this: sortedList.collect(Collectors.toList());
 But I get Result of 'Stream.collect()' is ignored ERROR. And when I run it returns SORTED LİST java.util.stream.SortedOps$OfRef@3e8c3cb

Comment: final List<String> collect = words.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()); this logic should work

Comment: @venkat I don't know why but it gets same result.  -->  public  List<String> getWords(String address) {

        String[] words = address.split("(/) | (,) | ( )");

        for (
                int i = 0;
                i < words.length; i++) {
                words[i] = words[i].replaceAll("[^\\w]", ",");
        }
        return Arrays.asList(words);
    }
I use this method. Can it be because of this method ?

Comment: @BatuhanBakar You're question says that your lists are simply a group of strings like  `"A","B","C","D"`.  So that is the what is expected.

Answer (score 1):

What you are actually displaying is a Stream. But what you want is the list of string used by this stream, change your code this way :

```
List<String> sortedList = WORD_OF_ADDRESS.stream()
                         .sorted()
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then display your list the way Johnny Mopp suggered

Comment: I got This ERROR : no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Object conforms to String inference variable T has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: String lower bounds: Object------> Required :  List<String>  Provided List<Object>

Comment: Look at my edited answer, i didn t noticed that your WORD_OF_ADDRESS was already a list

Comment: This didn't work it still comes same list.

Comment: public  List<String> getWords(String address) {

        String[] words = address.split("(/) | (,) | ( )");

        for (
                int i = 0;
                i < words.length; i++) {
                words[i] = words[i].replaceAll("[^\\w]", ",");
        }
        return Arrays.asList(words);
    }
I use this method. Can this be the reason ?

Answer (score -1):

You can sort the lists easily as follows:

```
List<String> WORD_OF_ADDRESS_sorted gatekeeperPage.getWords(ADDRESS)
    .stream().sorted().toList();
List<String> WORD_OF_CONTACT_ADDRESS_sorted = gatekeeperPage.getWords(CONTACT_ADDRESS)
    .stream().sorted().toList();
```

Then you can compare them.

However, if you just want to see if they are equal based on contents, sorting is not necessary to test for content equality.  Update a map with a running count each time the item occurs is more efficient. `Add 1` for one list and `subtract 1` for the other.  `Map.merge` is useful because it permits one to replace a `0` value with `null` which then removes the entry.  So if you end up with an empty map, the lists must be equal based on contents.

```
public static <T> boolean areEqual(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
    Map<T, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    if (list1.size() != list2.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
        map.merge(list1.get(i), -1,
                (k, v) -> v + 1 == 0 ? null : v + 1);
        map.merge(list2.get(i), 1,
                (k, v) -> v - 1 == 0 ? null : v - 1);
    }
    
    return map.isEmpty();
}
```

I have not extensively tested this but with the all tests using lists of random integers, where only one is copied shuffled tested as equal.   Randomly salting the lists with different values tested as false.

Since immutable lists are not altered, they can be passed directly to the method.

Caveat:  Since Integers have a maximum value and minimum value, extremely large lists have the potential to fail if those limits are reached.  Counting of `Long` or `BigInteger` would mitigate this problem but also decrease its performance.