# Convert List of Stream to List

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8

I have a lambda expression where I want to create a list of object but I am getting the error

```
List<ClassObject> classObject = obj1.getFileId().stream()
                .map(x -> obj1.getCustomObj().stream()
                        .map(y -> obj1.builder().Id(x).name(y.getName()).value(y.getValue())
                                .details(obj1.getDetails()).build()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Error

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Stream<ClassObject>> to List<ClassObject>
```

I want `List<ClassObject>` as return type from the lambda expression. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830313/retrieving-a-list-from-a-java-util-stream-stream-in-java-8 ?

Comment: Nope, that is not a good duplicate. The answer is flatmap() not map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use flatMap:

```
List<ClassObject> classObject = obj1.getFileId().stream()
            .flatMap(x -> obj1.getCustomObj().stream()
                    .map(y -> obj1.builder().Id(x).name(y.getName()).value(y.getValue())
                            .details(obj1.getDetails()).build()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```